# Cassandra: Unable to import null value from csv

Tags: string, import, null, cassandra, cqlsh

I am trying to import a csv file to Cassandra. The csv file has been generated from Postgres and it contains some null values.

Cassandra version:

> [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.5 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]

I am using this query to import:

> copy reports
>   (id,name,user_id,user_name,template_id,gen_epoch,exp_epoch,file_name,format,refile_size,is_sch,job_id,status,status_msg)
>   from '/home/reports.csv' with NULL='' and header=true and DELIMITER =
>   ',';

I keep on receiving this error:

> Failed to import 66 rows: ParseError - invalid literal for int() with
>   base 10: '',  given up without retries

However, when I changed all the null values to some random value, I was able to import that row using the same command. I have already tried all the solutions I found on internet.
Please advise.

Comment: Can you please post a preview of your `reports.csv` file somewhere ? The error message is talking about parsing integer, not about null value

Comment: id,name,user_id,user_name,template_id,gen_epoch,exp_epoch,file_name,format,refile_size,is_sch,job_id,status,status_msg 

1,S_C_T 2016-04-21-15-30-14,4,,6,1461277825,12,/S_C_T/S_C_T 2016-04-21-15-30-14.pdf,,72,0,,1,

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Cassandra bug (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11549). I haven't been able to find a way to get Cassandra to accept the nulls. You may have to stick with a workaround for now substitute some sentinel value for the nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You can put just empty field in the CSV.
I.e. I want to rewrite a value in DB to null - I can do something like:

```
cqlsh$> copy my_table(id,value_column1,value_column2) from 'myimport.csv';
```

And in myimport.csv, there will be

```
1234,,3
```

Like this, `value_column1` will have 'null' value.