# import data from Postgres to Cassandra

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, mapreduce

I need to **import data from Postgres to Cassandra** using **open source technologies only.** 
Can anyone please **outline the steps** I need to take.
As per instructions, I have to refrain from using DataStax software as they come with license.
Steps I have already tried:

Export one table from Postgres in csv format and imported to HDFS (using sqoop) {*If I take this approach do I need to use Map_Reduce after this?*}.

Tried to import the csv file to Cassandra using cql, however, got this error

> [Cassandra: Unable to import null value from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37622075/cassandra-unable-to-import-null-value-from-csv)

I am trying several methods, but unable to find a solid approach of attach.

Can anyone of you please provide me the steps required for the whole process. I believe there would be many people who have already done that.

Comment: Can you not use the Datastax Spark Connector? It's Apache Licensed that + Spark is a pretty easy way of doing it.

Comment: I want to do so. But we have been asked not to use Datastax softwares. Datastax license says that the license expires after 6 months.

Comment: No it doesn't ... https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

Comment: If that is so then I shall talk to my senior and discuss. However, will it work with Apache Cassandra as well (not the DSE)?  The free version of DSE is limited in license as per this link. http://www.datastax.com/enterprise-terms
Please also consider that we are not using Datastax Cassandra here.

--Thanks

Comment: It will work with OSS Apache Cassandra as well. You'll see all the tests in the project are against OSS C* as well.

Comment: Ok @RussS , thanks a lot!
So, I can do the whole data import from Postgres and import to Cassandra process using this Datastax Spark Connector?
Do we need to write some code as well? Or this tool is sufficient?

Comment: I have used DataStax and was able to import data using sqoop. The process is easy. We need to use the "dse sqoop --options-file <path>" and the file should have the details of the import options, like db credentials and table/schema name etc.